# Pass constructor arguments to member object

Tags: c++, c++17

I am sure this question has been answered before, but I am unable to find a satisfactory answer. Take the following example:

```
class A {
public:
    A(int a, int b, int c);

   //...
};

class B {
public:
    B(...);

private:
    A _a0;
    A _a1;
    A _a2;
    A _a3;
};
```

Class B contains multiple instances of class A.  I want to represent that B "owns" all of these instances.  From what I know, there are a couple ways to represent this

1. The instances of A are declare as direct members of B (as I have shown), and thus the memory of the A instances is directly inside the B class.
2. B contains a bunch of unique_ptr objects to the A classes
3. Use the Builder design pattern to do the creation on step at a time

The reason I don't want to use (2) and (3) is that I want NO heap allocation of these objects (I am writing for an embedded system).

The problem with (1) is, since each A requires 3 constructor parameters and these parameters are not provided by B but rather by the application writer (i.e., B merely owns and uses these instances of A but does not need to know how to create them), I have the bad option of passing 12 arguments to the constructor of B in order to create all 4 As.

I am wondering if another option would be to write the constructor of B such that it takes r-values to As and then move these As into B?

For example:

```
class B {
public:
    B(A&& a0, A&& a1, A&& a2, A&& a3) :
        _a0(std::move(a0)),
        _a1(std::move(a1)),
        _a2(std::move(a2)),
        _a3(std::move(a3))
    {

    }

private:
    A _a0;
    A _a1;
    A _a2;
    A _a3;
};
```

The one problem I can see which this solution is, what if A is a class which points/refers to some "global" resource.  The constructor of A should initialize this resource and the destructor should de-initialize this resource.  If A is moved, the reference/pointer to the resource also has to be moved AND the old copy of A has to be placed in some valid state which does not de-initialize the resource because ownership has been transferred.  What would be the correct way to represent this?

Comment: After moving `A` has to be in a valid state only in the sense that you can safely destroy it. It doesn't have to be "usable" anymore.

Comment: Correct way is to move 4  `A` objects, while making sure you have the destructor `~A` to check that before releasing resources it still holds them (so that the resources don't get released when moved-from object is destroyed from stack)

Answer (score 0):

So, your main problem is designing `class A`. From your description looks like it should be non-copyable, but move-constructible (and move-assignable):

> The one problem I can see which this solution is, what if A is a class
> which points/refers to some "global" resource. The constructor of A
> should initialize this resource and the destructor should
> de-initialize this resource. If A is moved, the reference/pointer to
> the resource also has to be moved AND the old copy of A has to be
> placed in some valid state which does not de-initialize the resource
> because ownership has been transferred.

The usual way to create such a class is by using `unique_ptr` with a custom deleter. Suppose, you have `class Resource` and

```
Resource* init_resource(int a);
void deinit_resource(Resource*);
```

Then, your `class A` may look like:

```
class A {
public:
    A(int a, int b, int c)
    : r( init_resource(a) )
    {
       //...
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Resource, deinit_resource> r;
    //...
};
```

With this `class A`, your constructor design of `class B` will work, but this is not the only way. If you like Builder pattern but cannot use dynamic memory, then `std::optional` is your friend. For example:

```
class B
{
public:
   B(){}
   void set_A1(int a, int b, int c)
   {
      a1_ = A(a, b, c);
   }
   //...
private:
   std::optional<A> a1_;
   //...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I put together that seems to work correctly

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <utility>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

/*
* Some global resource
* On an embedded system, this would be the peripherals/special-purpose registers
*/
static unsigned int resource1 = 0;
static unsigned int resource2 = 0;

/*
* Often, an SDK for an MCU will provide #define statements which contain the
* the start address (as an integer) of the peripheral register(s)
*/
#define RESOURCE1_ADDR (std::intptr_t)(&resource1)
#define RESOURCE2_ADDR (std::intptr_t)(&resource2)

template <typename T>
class ResourceManager;

/**
* @brief A handle to a particular resource managed by a ResourceManager
* @note Similar to unique_ptr, a ResourceHandle may only be moved
*/
template <typename T>
class ResourceHandle {
public:
    ~ResourceHandle() {
        std::cout << "ResourceHandle::~ResourceHandle()" << std::endl;
    }
    
    /**
    * @brief Helper method to release the resource managed by this handle back
    *        to its appropriate resource manager.
    */
    inline void release() {
        assert(_addr != 0);
        
        _manager.release(std::move(*this));
    }
    
    /**
    * @brief Copy constructor
    * @note Deleted because ResourceHandle is move-only
    */
    ResourceHandle(const ResourceHandle& other) = delete;
    
    /**
    * @brief Assignment operator
    * @note Deleted because ResourceHandle is move-only
    */
    const ResourceHandle& operator=(const ResourceHandle&) = delete;

    ResourceHandle(ResourceHandle&& other) :
        _manager(other._manager),
        _addr(other._addr)
    {
        std::cout << "ResourceHandle::ResourceHandle(ResourceHandle&&)" << std::endl;
        
        assert(_addr != 0);
        other._addr = 0;
    }
    
    ResourceHandle& operator=(ResourceHandle&& other) {
        std::cout << "ResourceHandle::operator=(ResourceHandle&&)" << std::endl;
        
        if (this != &other) {
            _addr = other._addr;
            other._addr = 0;
        }
        
        return *this;
    }
    
    operator T*() const { 
        assert(_addr != 0);
        return reinterpret_cast<T*>(_addr); 
    }
    T* operator->() const { return operator T*(); }
    
    inline bool isValid() const { return _addr != 0; }
    
protected:
    ResourceHandle(ResourceManager<T>& manager, std::intptr_t addr) : 
        _manager(manager),
        _addr(addr)
    {
        std::cout << "ResourceHandle::ResourceHandle(ResourceManager<T>&, std::intptr_t)" << std::endl;
    }
    
private:
    ResourceManager<T>& _manager;
    
    /**
    * @brief The integer address of the resource being mamaged by this handle
    * @note Set to 0 when invalid
    */
    std::intptr_t _addr;
    
    friend class ResourceManager<T>;
};

/**
* @brief Class which manages a particular resource by allowing a ResourceHandle
*        to be "obtained" and "released"
*/
template <typename T>
class ResourceManager {
public:
    constexpr ResourceManager(std::intptr_t addr) :
        _resource(*this, addr)
    {
        
    }
    
    constexpr ResourceHandle<T> obtain() {
        std::cout << "ResourceHandle::obtain()" << std::endl;
        
        assert(_resource.isValid());
        
        return std::move(_resource);
    }
    
    constexpr void release(ResourceHandle<T> r) {
        std::cout << "ResourceHandle::release()" << std::endl;
        
        assert(!_resource.isValid());
        
        _resource = std::move(r);
    }
    
private:
    ResourceHandle<T> _resource;
};

/**
* @brief Example class which "uses" (i.e., takes ownership of) a resource
*        via a ResourceHandle
*/
class ResourceUser {
public:
    ResourceUser(ResourceHandle<unsigned int> r) : 
        _r(std::move(r))
    {
        std::cout << "ResourceUser::ResourceUser(ResourceHandle<unsigned int>)" << std::endl;
        
        //Init
        std::cout << "ResourceUser -> Init resource" << std::endl;
        
        *_r = 0;
    }
    
    ~ResourceUser() {
        std::cout << "ResourceUser::~ResourceUser()" << std::endl;
        
        if (_r.isValid()) {
            std::cout << "ResourceUser -> Cleanup resource" << std::endl;
            
            *_r = 0;
            _r.release();
            
        }
    }
    
    ResourceUser(ResourceUser&& other) :
        _r(std::move(other._r))
    {
        std::cout << "ResourceUser::ResourceUser(ResourceUser&&)" << std::endl;
    }
    
    void set(unsigned int x) {
        std::cout << "ResourceUser::set()" << std::endl;
        
        *_r = x;
    }
    
private:
    ResourceHandle<unsigned int> _r;
};

/**
* @brief Example class which "owns" two ResourceUser objects
*/
class ResourceUserUser {
public:
    ResourceUserUser(ResourceUser&& a, ResourceUser&& b) :
        _a(std::move(a)),
        _b(std::move(b))
    {
        std::cout << "ResourceUserUser::ResourceUserUser()" << std::endl;
    }
    
    ~ResourceUserUser() {
        std::cout << "ResourceUserUser::~ResourceUserUser()" << std::endl;
    }
    
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "ResourceUserUser::foo()" << std::endl;
        
        _a.set(10);
        _b.set(20);
    }
    
private:
    ResourceUser _a;
    ResourceUser _b;
};

class Resource1 : public ResourceManager<unsigned int> {
public:
    inline static ResourceManager<unsigned int>& instance() { return _instance; }
    
private:
    static ResourceManager<unsigned int> _instance;
};

class Resource2 : public ResourceManager<unsigned int> {
public:
    inline static ResourceManager<unsigned int>& instance() { return _instance; }
    
private:
    static ResourceManager<unsigned int> _instance;
};

ResourceManager<unsigned int> Resource1::_instance(RESOURCE1_ADDR);
ResourceManager<unsigned int> Resource2::_instance(RESOURCE2_ADDR);

void test1() {
    std::cout << std::endl << "BEGIN test1()" << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "resource1 = " << resource1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "resource2 = " << resource2 << std::endl;
    
    ResourceUser user(Resource1::instance().obtain());
    user.set(20);
    
    std::cout << "resource1 = " << resource1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "resource2 = " << resource2 << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "END test1()" << std::endl;
}

void test2() {
    std::cout << std::endl << "BEGIN test2()" << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "resource1 = " << resource1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "resource2 = " << resource2 << std::endl;
    
    ResourceUserUser user(ResourceUser{Resource1::instance().obtain()}, ResourceUser{Resource2::instance().obtain()});
    user.foo();
    
    std::cout << "resource1 = " << resource1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "resource2 = " << resource2 << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "END test2()" << std::endl;
}

void test3() {
    std::cout << std::endl << "BEGIN test3()" << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "resource1 = " << resource1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "resource2 = " << resource2 << std::endl;
    
    ResourceUser user1(Resource1::instance().obtain());
    
    ResourceUserUser user2(ResourceUser{Resource1::instance().obtain()}, ResourceUser{Resource2::instance().obtain()});
    user2.foo();
    
    std::cout << "resource1 = " << resource1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "resource2 = " << resource2 << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "END test3()" << std::endl;
}
```

If you execute `test2()` the output is

```
ResourceHandle::ResourceHandle(ResourceManager<T>&, std::intptr_t)
ResourceHandle::ResourceHandle(ResourceManager<T>&, std::intptr_t)

BEGIN test2()
resource1 = 0
resource2 = 0
ResourceHandle::obtain()
ResourceHandle::ResourceHandle(ResourceHandle&&)
ResourceHandle::ResourceHandle(ResourceHandle&&)
ResourceUser::ResourceUser(ResourceHandle<unsigned int>)
ResourceUser -> Init resource
ResourceHandle::obtain()
ResourceHandle::ResourceHandle(ResourceHandle&&)
ResourceHandle::ResourceHandle(ResourceHandle&&)
ResourceUser::ResourceUser(ResourceHandle<unsigned int>)
ResourceUser -> Init resource
ResourceHandle::ResourceHandle(ResourceHandle&&)
ResourceUser::ResourceUser(ResourceUser&&)
ResourceHandle::ResourceHandle(ResourceHandle&&)
ResourceUser::ResourceUser(ResourceUser&&)
ResourceUserUser::ResourceUserUser()
ResourceUser::~ResourceUser()
ResourceHandle::~ResourceHandle()
ResourceHandle::~ResourceHandle()
ResourceUser::~ResourceUser()
ResourceHandle::~ResourceHandle()
ResourceHandle::~ResourceHandle()
ResourceUserUser::foo()
ResourceUser::set()
ResourceUser::set()
resource1 = 10
resource2 = 20
END test2()
ResourceUserUser::~ResourceUserUser()
ResourceUser::~ResourceUser()
ResourceUser -> Cleanup resource
ResourceHandle::ResourceHandle(ResourceHandle&&)
ResourceHandle::release()
ResourceHandle::operator=(ResourceHandle&&)
ResourceHandle::~ResourceHandle()
ResourceHandle::~ResourceHandle()
ResourceUser::~ResourceUser()
ResourceUser -> Cleanup resource
ResourceHandle::ResourceHandle(ResourceHandle&&)
ResourceHandle::release()
ResourceHandle::operator=(ResourceHandle&&)
ResourceHandle::~ResourceHandle()
ResourceHandle::~ResourceHandle()
ResourceHandle::~ResourceHandle()
ResourceHandle::~ResourceHandle()
```

I am curious though, is there any way I can get rid of those extra calls to the move constructor?  For example, the ResourceManager calls the move constructor to move the handle out of itself, then the ResourceUser calls the move constructor again.